# how to use updateMany to update all multiple documents - mongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

So i am creating Nodejs API. I want to add products to a category collection for products. My product model has multiple categories in an array,

**Product model**

```
var productSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    productSKU: String,
    productName: String
    productCategory: Array,
});
```

**Category model**

```
var categorySchema = mongoose.Schema({
    categoryID: String,
    categoryName: String,
    product: [productSchema],
});
```

I want to add product to each separate category to the category collection from the category array in the product model. How can i achieve that with mongoose `updateMany` query?

below is my controller to fill category collection

```
    let query = {
        categoryID: categoryID
    }

    let update = {
        $push: {
            product: product,
        }
    }

    let options = {
        safe: true,
        new: true,
        upsert: true,
        multi: true
    }

 return CategoryProduct.updateMany(query, update, options).exec()
```

Comment: Just to clarify: You wan't a query, that'll fetch the I'ds of all products, which have a productCategory that includes the CategoryID you are currently looking at, and then add it to the product array of said category?

Comment: the product object contains category array, i want to fill the category collection with product based on the categories in the category array. i would prefer to return a promise so i will use `.exec`